# When I tell rvm to install ruby 1.9.2 It ends up installing 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-1.9

Well, when I run rvm install 1.9.2. It tells me to issue `rvm reinstall 1.9.2`. Though, when I do so, I get 1.8.7 reinstalled. 1.8.7 is the only interpreter listed by `rvm list`.

The O.S. is Ubuntu without rvm-ruby installed. Rvm is at its latest version.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the .rvmrc file from my home directory and then issuing `rvm install 1.9.2`.

Comment: I'll do that when I am allowed (in two days). :-)